# Pandasで複数条件を指定して抽出を行うには？

Tags: python, python3, pandas

以下に示すデータフレームがあります。city2のTokyoを抽出したいのですが、エラーが出ました。
どのようなコードを書けば良いでしょうか？ご教授頂けると幸いです。

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
ValueError: iLocation based boolean indexing cannot use an indexable as a mask
```

**実行したコード:**

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("file.csv",index_col=0)
df1_1 = df1.iloc[df1['city2'] == "Tokyo" ]
```

**対象のデータフレーム:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

マルチインデックスで読み込んでみるのもよいかと思います。(`read_csv()` に `header=[0, 1]` を指定)

```py
# Pandas read_csv
import pandas as pd
import io

csv_data = '''
,city1,city1,city1,city2,city2,city2
,Tokyo,Osaka,Nagoya,Tokyo,Osaka,Nagoya
2023/7/1 0:30,4355,44022,51568,45060,48214,6435
2023/7/2 0:30,8372,17772,55602,43017,46247,4357
2023/7/3 0:30,3256,16834,60295,41278,45249,9654
2023/7/4 0:30,3567,42440,67965,39726,44097,5722
2023/7/5 0:30,9843,81794,75601,38656,42693,3567
'''
df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_data), index_col=0, header=[0, 1])
print(df1)

df1_1 = df1[[('city2', 'Tokyo')]]
print(df1_1)

#               city1                city2
#               Tokyo  Osaka Nagoya  Tokyo  Osaka Nagoya
# 2023/7/1 0:30  4355  44022  51568  45060  48214   6435
# 2023/7/2 0:30  8372  17772  55602  43017  46247   4357
# 2023/7/3 0:30  3256  16834  60295  41278  45249   9654
# 2023/7/4 0:30  3567  42440  67965  39726  44097   5722
# 2023/7/5 0:30  9843  81794  75601  38656  42693   3567
#
#                city2
#                Tokyo
# 2023/7/1 0:30  45060
# 2023/7/2 0:30  43017
# 2023/7/3 0:30  41278
# 2023/7/4 0:30  39726
# 2023/7/5 0:30  38656
```

Comment: 少し追加したい質問ですが、左の上から空欄にunitとlocationに入れたいですが、
私はこう書きました。
df1_1=df1_1.rename(columns={'':'unit'},index={'':'location'})
結果はunitが入れた。locationはなかった。問題点はどちらですか。

Comment: read_csv の直後に `df1.columns.names = ['unit', 'location']` を入れてみてください。もしくは、`df1_1` だけにセットしたい場合は `df1_1.columns.names = ['unit', 'location']` とします。

Answer (score 0):

同じ列名を持つデータフレームは、`read_csv`で読み込んだ時点で、次のような列名になるかと思います。

[image]

前提となっているデータフレーム(df1)の構造を変えた方が以降も扱いやすいかと思いますので、元のcsvファイルを使って、先頭の行のみが列名となるように書き換えます。

**city2を含むデータフレームの取得**

```py
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv('test.csv',index_col=0)

# 対象となる文字列
word = 'city2'
# 対象文字列を含む列名を取得
characters = [column for column in df1.columns if word in column]
# 対象のデータフレーム
city2 = df.loc[:,column_inc_specific_char]
```

[image]

```py
columns = city2.iloc[0,:].values
index = city2.iloc[1:,:].index
data = city2.iloc[1:,:].values
df_new = pd.DataFrame(data=data, index=index, columns=columns )
```

[image]

あとは、`df_new['Tokyo']`で該当する部分を抽出すればOKです。

もしくは、このようなデータでしたら、辞書オブジェクトで扱っても良いと思います。